# On the second floor?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

The wording: <strike>"другой наверну"</strike> "другой наверху".

I have not been able to do some research on this and I was hoping for someone to help me out a little. I need input on the "grammatika". What type of word "другой" is. Is it adaped to наверну?. Is наверну dativ?

Comment: Can you add more context, please? What are you trying to say?

Comment: Could you provide more context? If there are no typos, **наверну** is likely a verb (1st person future tense) which can have different meanings (technical or slang). **Другой** could mean _a different / another one / one more_.

Comment: "у него два туалета - один внизу, другой наверзу."                     Sorry for the delay. I am doing some other things in parallel. I am enclosing the full sentence from my textbook. I am curious if the last part includes a dativ and what is the word другой in type of grammar?

Comment: @Ana, the correct form is "другой *наверху*", that is "the other one – on the higher floor"

Comment: The complete sentence would be "He's got two bathrooms: one of them on the lower floor of the apartment and the other one on the higher floor".

Comment: большой Спасибо! Costed me -2. Sorry about that I was stressed out and I still am stressed out. I will improve the quality. Saving both yours and mine time. I will work harder on that one and improve my planning.

Comment: @Ana, I guess you meant "Большо́e спаси́бо!" – it's just alright to ask for help when you study a new language; you may provide some information about yourself in your [profile](http://russian.stackexchange.com/users/6096/ana) so that others better realize what you need; also you need to mark the answers (and comments) that were useful to you – at least as a sign of appreciation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I highly appreciate that you took to explain this to me. I was not fully aware of how things work in this forum so I have started to mark the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no typos, **наверну** is a verb (1st person future tense) which can have different meanings (technical - ***to screw on*** or slang - ***to eat***, ***to dig in***). Другой could mean ***a different / another one / one more***.

However, the question title makes me think there is a typo, and the phrase is:

> Другой, наверно.

**Наверно** is *вводное слово* gramatically, meaning ***probably*** in English.

UPDATE:

So the full sentence is:

> У него два туалета - один внизу, другой наверху.

**Другой** is an adjective, nominative case. The noun is omitted to avoid repetition, but you could also say:

> У него два туалета - один туалет находится внизу, другой туалет наверху.

**Наверху** is an adverb, meaning ***upstairs***.

Answer (score 0):

If it's spelled exactly *наверну*, then it's 1st person singular of "*навернуть*", i.e. "[I] will screw another one". This seems to be a sort of jargon speech, but note, unlike in English, "screw" in Russian colloquial speech usually means simply "eat". That is, "I'm gonna eat another one".

But without any context, it's only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Другой (adjective) — other, another, different
Наверну (verb, singular first person, future tense) — to screw.

It is not sentence, not a phrase, just two separate words. It needs a context to answer correctly.

Example:
— Этот колпачок не от этого тюбика. — This cap is not of this tube.
— Хорошо, я **другой наверну**. — Okay, I'm screw another one.

Probably a typo, not `наверну` but `наверное` ?